# Solving RC circuit with python/sympy

Tags: python, physics, sympy

I'm working independently out the the book Computational Physics by Mark Newman, exercise 6.5 to be specific (it can be downloaded [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/cp/exercises.html)). The problem is to solve for node voltages in an RC circuit driven by a complex exponential source voltage.

What I would like to do is turn my node equations into the form **Av** = **B**. Here is what I'm doing so far.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy

# Define constants
R1=R3=R5 = 1e3
R2=R4=R6 = 2e3
C1 = 1e-6
C2 = 0.5e-6
x_plus = 3
x_minus = 0
w = 1000

# Define relations
V_plus = sympy.symbols('V_plus')
t = sympy.symbols('t')

V_plus = x_plus*sympy.exp(1j*w*t)
V_minus = 0

V1,V2,V3 = sympy.symbols('V1 V2 V3')

V1_eqn = (V1-V_plus)/R1 + (V1-V2)/(1/(1j*w*C1)) + (V1-V_minus)/R4
V2_eqn = (V2-V_plus)/R2 + (V2-V1)/(1/(1j*w*C1)) + (V2-V_minus)/R5 + (V2-V3)/(1/(1j*w*C2))
V3_eqn = (V3-V_plus)/R3 + (V3-V2)/(1/(1j*w*C2)) + (V3-V_minus)/R6

# Prepare
V = [V1,V2,V3]
V_vec = np.matrix(V)

A = np.matrix([
    [V1_eqn.expand().coeff(x) for x in V],
    [V2_eqn.expand().coeff(x) for x in V],
    [V3_eqn.expand().coeff(x) for x in V]
    ])
print(A)
```

Now, the problem I'm having is extracting the constant terms of the three equations so I can load them into **B**. Among other things, one of the issues is that the "constant term" isn't actually constant. It's a complex exponential function of 't'. Since this is a fairly straightforward problem with pen and paper, I know exactly what the constant term is going to look like, so I can extract it. My goal though is to solve this in a way that doesn't require knowing the answer ;).

One method I've considered is taking each equation and subtracting off all the terms that I've already put in **Av**, but this seems a little sloppy and not very pythonic. Does anyone know of a better method for extracting constant terms that aren't technically constant? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for some shortcuts in notation, subtracting the terms you've already put into `A` is exactly what you should, and must, do.

Here's a slightly shorter version:

```
import sympy

# Define constants
R1=R3=R5 = 1e3
R2=R4=R6 = 2e3
C1 = 1e-6
C2 = 0.5e-6
x_plus = 3
x_minus = 0
w = 1000

# Define relations
V_plus = sympy.symbols('V_plus')
t = sympy.symbols('t')

V_plus = x_plus*sympy.exp(1j*w*t)
V_minus = 0

V1,V2,V3 = sympy.symbols('V1 V2 V3')

# Using a matrix to collect all equations allows you to use a matrix-vector-product below
eqns = sympy.matrices.Matrix([
    (V1-V_plus)/R1 + (V1-V2)/(1/(1j*w*C1)) + (V1-V_minus)/R4,
    (V2-V_plus)/R2 + (V2-V1)/(1/(1j*w*C1)) + (V2-V_minus)/R5 + (V2-V3)/(1/(1j*w*C2)),
    (V3-V_plus)/R3 + (V3-V2)/(1/(1j*w*C2)) + (V3-V_minus)/R6
])

# Prepare
V = [V1,V2,V3]
V_vec = sympy.matrices.Matrix(V)

# The "or 0" does nothing if there are coefficients y in x, but if there aren't, it replaced
# the "None" with "0". This again is required for using A * V_vec below
A = sympy.matrices.Matrix([ [ x.expand().coeff(y) or 0 for y in V ] for x in eqns ])

print(A)

remainder = (eqns - A * V_vec)
remainder.simplify()
print remainder
```

Comment: Maybe unpythonic just because I'm not very experienced with python haha. I guess I kind of expected that functionality to be part of sympy even though I couldn't find it. I'm going to leave the question open a little longer and see if I get any other suggestions. Thanks Phillip.

Comment: Another way to get the constants is to substitute `{V1:0,V2:0,V3:0}` in each equation, e.g. `[ x.subs({V1:0,V2:0,V3:0}) for x in eqns ]`

Comment: Thank you @user5402. I can't believe that wasn't my first thought lol. All those years of calculus just failed me haha. I timed the two methods and from the very very basic test I just ran, subbing zeros is several orders of magnitude faster than the subtraction method. I'm going to accept Phillip's answer since it was slightly more pertinent to what I'm doing, but subbing zeros as suggested by user5402 is really the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can just solve it directly with `sympy.solve`:

```
import sympy as sp

R1=R3=R5 = 1e3
R2=R4=R6 = 2e3
C1 = 1e-6
C2 = 0.5e-6
w = 1000
V0 = 5

t = sp.Symbol('t')
E = sp.exp(1j*w*t)

V1, V2, V3 = sp.symbols('V1 V2 V3')

V_plus = V0*E
V_minus = 0

V1_eqn = (V1-V_plus)/R1 + (V1-V2)/(1/(1j*w*C1)) + (V1-V_minus)/R4
V2_eqn = (V2-V_plus)/R2 + (V2-V1)/(1/(1j*w*C1)) + (V2-V_minus)/R5 + (V2-V3)/(1/(1j*w*C2))
V3_eqn = (V3-V_plus)/R3 + (V3-V2)/(1/(1j*w*C2)) + (V3-V_minus)/R6

print sp.solve([ sp.Eq(V1_eqn, 0), sp.Eq(V2_eqn, 0), sp.Eq(V3_eqn, 0)], [V1, V2, V3] )
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but since I'm working out of a book specifically designed to teach numerical methods in physics, I'm intentionally not using the some of the handy built in functions like solve, though they may well be faster (I didn't check). Your comment below Phillip's answer is the real answer to my question though. I'm hoping the way I picked the answer will help anyone else to the answer you provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting zeros is a good way to get the constants that remain. Also, the `jacobian` method is a more "mathematical" way of doing what you were doing with the `coeff` method.

```
>>> eqs = sympy.Matrix((V1_eqn, V2_eqn, V3_eqn))
>>> eqs.jacobian(V)
Matrix([
[0.0015 + 0.001*I,          -0.001*I,                 0],
[        -0.001*I, 0.0015 + 0.0015*I,         -0.0005*I],
[               0,         -0.0005*I, 0.0015 + 0.0005*I]])
```